# Getting "FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#324) Requires upload file" when trying to post image

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm currently in charge of implementing several new features to a social network app, one of them is whenever the user posts an image it automatically gets posted on the user's facebook as well (exactly the same way Instagram does). So far I came up with this:

```
FBSDKAccessToken *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"message" : @"some text",
                             @"picture" : @"http://fanaru.com/doge/image/18353-doge-os-x-doge.jpg",
                             };

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:parameters tokenString:token.tokenString version:@"v2.3" HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    else
        NSLog(@"Success");
}];

[connection start];
```

but every time I run it I get this error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)" UserInfo=0x166a64d0 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=324, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
>           body =     {
>               error =         {
>               code = 324;
>               message = "(#324) Requires upload file";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 400;
>   }, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400,   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#324) Requires upload file,   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}

I understand I need to upload the image to the facebook servers but I simply have no idea on how to do this. Already read tons of pages from the Facebook SDK documentation and still haven't got any solution. Ideally I will also need to create a new photo album specifically for this app but solving the problem above is my main concern right now.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just so you know, if I change the graphpath to "me/feed" it works just fine, put the picture is posted as a link, so still not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error it's giving you is right. It doesn't want a URL it asked you for a file and that file wasn't included. You need to download your image first if you don't already have it and include the image data in the parameters.

```
UIImage *image = (some picture I downloaded);
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                               @"message" : @"some text",
                               @"picture" : UIImagePNGRepresentation(image),
                            };
```

Comment: giving me this error FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#100) picture is not properly formatted